# Logitech k350 won't type on PC and now I can't get into WIN 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, logitech-keyboard

I'm typing this on my laptop as I can't enter any keystrokes on my desktop pc.

My K350 just quit typing letters while I was in the middle of an on-line quiz.
I followed one person's suggestion to remove the device software and reboot the system.  But the keyboard still does not type any letters or numbers.  So now I can't type in my pin to get into WIN 10 and fix this.

I also tried using a microsoft usb keyboard on my desktop and that doesn't work either. The green light on the keyboard tells me the keyboard isn't broken.

I paired the 350 keyboard with my laptop and can type on the laptop. I tried inserting the pairing device into a slot on my desktop but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions on how to fix this so I can get into win10 on my desktop computer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use a plain USB Keyboard on this machine?  I would suggest if you can to open an Admin Command prompt and run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  . Follow this with SFC /SCANNOW.  Allow everything to complete, restart and test.

Comment: I tried using a microsoft usb keyboard  but that won't type any letters or numbers on my desktop either.  I'm totally flummoxed.

Comment: You can get to the logon screen.  Can you RDP to it (Windows RDP) from your Laptop?

Comment: I'm trying it now... I need the ip address of the computer sitting right next to me.  I think I can get it from my home network settings.

Comment: Addendum.  I don't recall enabling a remote hookup when I installed win 10 on my desktop.  I looked on my laptop and it's enabled, so I'm hoping that enable remote is the default  setting

Comment: Log into your home router and look in the network or connection settings and see what the desktop IP is. There should not be too many IP's so you can try the ones that are there.

Comment: No. I can't get in to my desktop remotely

Comment: Oh, didn't see your latest comment.  Trying to see the router settings.

Comment: Bad news.  Start with a bootable USB Key, recover your data and then rebuild the computer with a Windows ISO USB

Comment: Yeah, I had already used ipconfig to get my ipv4 addr.  it didn't work.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't thought of booting with a key.  I had used some great software when I was building this pc so I could get files off of a backup drive.  I'll try to find that software again.  Will my keyboard work after I go through this process?  I appreciate your help so much.  thanks

Comment: Once you have your files, start the Windows 10 Installation. That is fresh and the basic keyboard should work.

Comment: I first want to thank you for all of your help.  I solved the problem by hitting the computer icon at the bottom right of my screen, which took me to settings, where I found the filter key was turned on.  I turned it off and my keyboard now works.